# Linux Shell: how to get sshd port and PID

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I use following command:

```
sudo netstat -tnp | grep sshd
```

The output is:

```
tcp        0      0 192.201.0.8:22          192.201.0.90:2690       ESTABLISHED 1866/sshd: yang [pr
```

Than, I use following command:

```
$ echo -n "sshd Port&&pid: " ; sudo netstat -tnp | grep sshd | awk '{print $4, $7}' | sed -r 's/^[^:]*:([a-z]*)/\1/g'
```

The output is:

```
sshd Port&&pid: 22 1866/sshd:
```

Finally, using following command:

```
$ echo -n "sshd Port&&pid: " ; sudo netstat -tnp | grep sshd | awk '{print $4, $7}' | sed -r 's/^[^:]*:([a-z]*)/\1/g; s/([0-9]*)\/sshd:$/\1/g'
```

The output is:

```
sshd Port&&pid: 22 1866
```

Although I have solved my problem, is there a better way to do that?

Another answer:

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep "sshd" | grep -v "\]" | sed -r 's/.*:([0-9]+).* ([0-9]*)\/.*$/sshd Port\&\&pid: \1 \2/' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: *Very low quality:* What have you tried?

Comment: @DannyBeckett I edited my question add what have I tried, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
$ echo foo/bar | sed 's,/.*,,'
foo
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You're over-thinking the problem:

```
netstat -anp | awk -F"[: /]" '/sshd/{printf "sshd Port&&pid: %s %s\n", $5,$9 }'
sshd Port&&pid: 22 1866
```

That is: this works on MY machine, your netstats output may differ.